# How Updating IPNS link works

Tags: ipfs

I have a directory which contains a number of files that I have added to ipfs.
When I do this I get a list of all the hashes for the files contained in the directory.

For example:

```
File1.txt QYNOSMSLDFKAL12345
File2.txt QYNOSMSLDFKAL12346
File3.txt QYNOSMSLDFKAL12347
```

I now publish this ipfs hash of the directory to ipns, and try to get File2.txt
by using the following gateway link:

```
http://ipfs.io/ipns/<ipns hash>/File2.txt
```

How when somebody tries to get a file on the gateway, how exactly does it find where the ipns hash is located? (and subsequently the files contained in the directory linked to that hash)

I ask this because I am wondering what happens in the following situation:

I now modify File1.txt in the directory that I have hashed previously. When I re-add the directory I notice that only the hash of File1.txt has changed, which makes sense. Now I have:

```
File1.txt QYNOSMSLDFKAL99999
File2.txt QYNOSMSLDFKAL12346
File3.txt QYNOSMSLDFKAL12347
```

I now republish this to the same ipns link as before.

Now when somebody tries to get a file that the ipfs gateway has previously served which has not changed - eg. File2.txt - does the gateway have to start from scratch when trying to find this File2.txt, even though it's ipfs hash is identical from before, and it's ipns link would be identical?

ie. http://ipfs.io/ipns//File2.txt

The point I am getting at, is there a massive overhead with updating IPNS links if most of the files contained in the new directory are unchanged?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the gateway and use a link containing IPNS, the content is downloaded every time you look up the link. At most there might be a cache header for a few seconds. This is unavoidable since the value of an IPNS name can change at any time.

If you interact directly with IPFS, resolution of a path like `/ipns/<ipns hash>/File2.txt` is a two step process. First the IPNS name gets translated into an IPFS hash. Then the content at that hash is traversed to the leaf.

So for the above path to resolve, the IPNS name must *currently* point to an IPFS hash that is a directory object having a child called `File2.txt`.

If you are *not* using the gateway, your local IPFS daemon will notice that while the directory object has changed, the `File2.txt` still has the hash `QYNOSMSLDFKAL12346` and will *not* download it again.

Comment: What happens when I host the IPNS link to the IPFS directory as a website using dnslink?

Comment: It is essentially the same, except that IPFS will recognise that the string is not a key and will then do a DNS TXT record lookup. If the result of the TXT record lookup is a ipfs hash, it will *then* traverse the corresponding directory.